# toggle divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html and I want to use jQuery to toggle the display/visibility of the child divs in the `product-preview-wrapper` div. This is to be done by selecting which one to show by selecting `OPTION_one`, `OPTION_two` or `OPTION_three` from the `product-image-wrapper` div. Also `OPTION_one` needs to be selected be default at run time (hiding `STUFF_two` and `STUFF_three`).

```
<div class="product-preview-wrapper">
  <div id="wrap">STUFF_one</div>
  <div id="wrap">STUFF_two</div>
  <div id="wrap">STUFF_three</div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-wrapper">
  <div class="product-img-thumb-small">OPTION_one</div>
  <div class="product-img-thumb-small">OPTION_two</div>
  <div class="product-img-thumb-small">OPTION_three</div>
</div>
```

I know there's something with indexing but I couldn't get my head around it. I also need the function to allow for different amounts of content... there wont always be 3 child divs to toggle.

I played with toggle,hide & show and css('display', 'none') and fell a bit short with my experience.

I haven't posted my try code here as it didn't work and is a total mess anyway.

Any advice/direction with this would be much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the same `id` for multiple elements. `id` is **unique**!

Once you fix that, make use of `.index()`:

```
$('.product-image-wrapper .product-img-thumb-small').click(function() {
  $('.product-preview-wrapper')
   .children()
   .eq($(this).index())
   .show()
   .siblings()
   .hide();
});

// To load the first one
$('.product-image-wrapper .product-img-thumb-small').eq(0).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @blender. I can't change the wrap id. Is auto generated by the Cloud Zoom module (in drupal 7).

Comment: I did the above but got the error: 

`Error: $(".product-image-wrapper .product-img-thumb-small").on is not a function`

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question but how do I have it default to only show the first one on load.

Comment: What version of jQuery? You must be using something *ancient*. Try this.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  The [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method was added in version 1.7.

Comment: `$('.product-image-wrapper .product-img-thumb-small').eq(0).click();
` doesn't seem to work for hiding all but the first on load. Is that a version issue too?

Comment: I think the Cloud Zoom script is resetting inline style after this runs. does that sound possible.

Comment: it's cool, I set them all to display none in the css and it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

toggle should work. Try setting you div display as inline and then use toggle.